# Selecting unique rows from a table having duplicate values in only one column

Tags: vertica

I have a table containing zip codes and city areas. The data  is such that multiple zip codes can refer to the same area. It currently looks like this.

```
ZIP          CITY AREA
1            A
2            B
2            A 
3            C
3            A
4            D
```

I want to remove the duplicate occurrences so that the table looks like this:

```
ZIP          CITY AREA
1            A
2            B
3            C 
4            D
```

I don't mind which city area is mapped to a zipcode, but am unable to remove the duplicates using Distinct().
I understand of the question is a simple one but am new to SQL and any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Vertica? They are different databases.

Comment: I'm using VerticaDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `GROUP BY`, which is [supported by Vertica](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/SELECT/GROUPBYClause.htm):

```
SELECT city_area, MIN(ZIP) AS ZIP
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY city_area;
```

Your sample data, while brief, seems to imply that you want to select the smallest `ZIP` value for each city area, should a city area have more than one record.

Comment: Hi Tim, Just to clarify, The City Area column contains names of neighborhoods, and not actual area values. Would this solution still work for that?

Comment: Yes, this should still be applicable.  Where it might _not_ work is if your ZIP values are actual 5 digit ZIP codes, and you have some other logic for which one to take from among several ZIP codes in an area.  In that case, you would have to update your question with real data.

Comment: Yup Done and Done.